# Angular: Wrap providers in a module?

Tags: angular

The number of providers I have is growing:

#### app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
  RegistrationService, LoginService,
  LoginPageGuard, LoggedInGuard, VerifiedGuard,
  LoggedInAndVerifiedGuard, UnverifiedGuard,
  NotLoggedInGuard
],
```

I was able to do something like this with modules:

#### my-material.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdMenuModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdMenuModule
  ],


declarations: []
})
export class MyMaterialModule {
}
```

And then just include that module in my app module. Can something similar be done with services / providers?

The main reason I ask is because I am writing tests for components and e2e tests. Rather than copy / paste my providers and services I thought I could just include the encapsulated services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services in Angular do not have module encapsulation, except for lazy loaded modules. Once the module they are defined in is loaded, they are registered in the root injector. So, you can have `A`,`B`,`C` modules with providers, then just import them to `D` module, and import this D module into the main app module.

Comment: So, my main reason for asking this is for use in tests. I was having all sorts of "no provider for X" failures, so I started copying them in my tests.

Comment: @Jeff, can you add these details to the question?